# Add a new contextual link to custom block type to edit layout

Tags: blocks, 9, layout-builder

I have a custom block type using Layout Builder.

How do I add an *Edit Layout* item in the contextual link menu?

The link should go to /block/{nid}/layout; after saving, the layout returns to where you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this by implementing *.links.contextual.yml in a module. For example, to add a contextual link on Nodes to node layout builder, you would implement the following: `[MODULE].links.contextual.yml`

```
node_layout:
  title: 'Edit Layout'
  route_name: 'layout_builder.overrides.node.view'
  group: 'node'
```

You can find out the route_name for various entities by enabling the Devel module, and going to `/devel/routes`.

Comment: Thank you. Where would I place this file? And is there any other code to write?

Comment: It goes in a custom module. This solution requires an understanding of how to create custom modules in Drupal.

Comment: I have a custom module working. I've tried placing the file in the module's main folder and then config folder, to no success.

Comment: In the module root, and clear the cache. Also make sure the module is enabled

Comment: Ah, that's the ticket. Thank you!